# Trigger a method in a functional component after click on a button from a different component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, frontend

I am trying to trigger a method in a functional component while having the name of a different component, or the id provided as props. Is this possible?

Basically my component would subscribe to something and whenever the provided component name / id would be clicked, I would also trigger a method in my function.

The behavior would represent having some kind of custom script component, in which the user would provide a script which is triggered either on load, after interval, and clicking on a different component. Managed to do the first ones, but have no idea how to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Parent component:

```
  import { View, Text } from "react-native";
  import { useState } from "react";
  import ChildComp from "./ChildComp";
  import ButtonComp from "./ButtonComp";

  export default function ParentComp() {
      const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
      const clickHandler = () => {
          // by changing the value we show that the button has clicked 
          setClicked((clicked) => (clicked = !clicked));
      };
      return (
          <View>
             <ChildComp clicked={clicked}></ChildComp>
             <ButtonComp clickHandler={clickHandler}></ButtonComp>
          </View>
      );
  };
```

Child component where the code needs to be triggered as the button has clicked in a sibling component:

```
  import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
  import { Text, View } from "react-native";

  let clickedTotal = 0;

  export default function ChildComp(props) {
      const { clicked } = props;

      useEffect(     
          (clicked) => {
             // this code runs as the button has clicked in ButtonComp
             clickedTotal = clickedTotal + 1;
          }, [clicked]
      );
      return (
          <View>
              <Text>the button clicked {clickedTotal} times</Text>
          </View>
      };
   };
```

ButtonComp component with a button:

```
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

export default function ButtonComp(props) {
  const { clickHandler } = props;    
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={(e) => clickHandler(e)}>
        <Text>CLICK ME</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  ); 
}
```